# Where or how is C++Builder Application->Title set?

Tags: c++builder

I use `Application->Title` to get the name in a generic routine that saves items to the registry.

The problem is, the `Title` that is returned has its first letter capitalized and all others lower case, whereas the project and `.exe` created have mixed-case, which looks a lot better.

I'd like the registry key to be the same without having to hard-code the name.  To do that, where is the `Application->Title` coming from?

Note that `Details` from `Version Information` look correct in the generated `.exe`.

Comment: I have never used C++Builder, but in Delphi, you set `Application.Title` in Project > Options> Application > Appearance > Application settings > Title. This GUI control writes to the line `Application.Title := '...'` in the .dpr file (Project > View Source). Again: I have no idea how this works in C++Builder.

Comment: Why not simply use the .EXE filename instead: ChangeFileExt(ExtractFileName(Application.ExeName),'')

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand it works the same way in C++Builder, updating the corresponding `Application->Title = "...";` line in the project's main `.cpp` file.